# Jupyter Notebook - OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted

Tags: python, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have an external python function that I want to run inside a Jupyter Notebook. It executes, among others, `os` method `setpgrp`:

```
os.setpgrp()
```

When I run the function it gives me the following error:

> OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted

The code works fine (there are no errors or warnings) when I call the method from normal python `.py` script or directly from console. The problem occurs only in Jupyter Notebook.

I got the same error when I run the following code directly in notebook:

```
import os
os.setpgrp()
```

I changed the permission and ownership to all related files, run Jupyter with `sudo` but it didn't change anything.

OS: Lubuntu 16.04

Do you have any ideas what can cause this error?